# Sorting n strings using Merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

A list of n strings each of length n is sorted into lexicographic order using the merge sort algorithm. The worst case running time of this computation is?

I searched this question and everywhere I found the answer to be: O(n<sup>2</sup>logn).

While my approach is as follows:
Comparing two strings require O(n) comparisons, hence each merge will take O(n<sup>2</sup>) time.
So, the recurrence equation will be:
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n<sup>2</sup>)
Therefore, by Master Method:
T(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis and reduction is correct. But the problem is in the interpretation of recurrence equation of master theorem.

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n<sup>2</sup>)

The n in the equation represents no.of elements in the list to be sorted. 
The O(n<sup>2</sup>) is not entirely correct. It is O(n * n-character comparisons). 
This will be evident if we substitute 'n-character comparisons' operations with a different complexity, which is independent of no.of elements.
Let it be O(m).
Then we have

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n * m)

we have a = 2, b = 2, c = 1 and c = Log<sub>b</sub>a  (case 2)

Hence,
T(n) = O(n * m * log n)

Now, substituting m with n

**T(n) = O(n<sup>2</sup> * log n)**

We can also justify this as - the recurrence tree for merge sort will have height Log(n). O(n<sup>2</sup>) work will be done at each level of the recurrence tree in merge operation.

Hence, a total of **O (n<sup>2</sup> log n)**

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your conclusion of `O(n^2*lgn)` is correct.  If you were dealing with a set of `n` numbers, we know that mergesort would require `O(nlgn)`.  The difference here is that we are now dealing with strings, each of which is `n` long.  The only impact on the mergesort algorithm would be the comparison of two strings in the base case.  Instead of an `O(1)` comparison of two numbers, we would instead have to compare the two strings.  In the general case, this is an `O(n)` operation, because we might have to walk down each of the two length `n` strings.

Comment: What do you mean by each string is O(nlgn)?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Do dogs really meow?

Comment: Is the answer to my question really that obvious? I don't think the OP means to sort the strings themselves internally

Comment: My understanding of the question is that we have `n` strings, each of whose characters must be sorted.  Since each string has `n` characters, then sorting via mergesort would be an `O(nlgn)` operation, `O(n^2*lgn)` for all `n` strings.  But there is a second part to the question, namely sorting the `n` words.  This again is an `O(nlgn)` operation; but it doesn't change the overall running time.  But maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: I think OP means to sort the strings as they would be in a dictionary (hence *lexicographic order*)

Answer (score 0):

arunk2's answer is correct, but here are some more details of exactly where the recurrence is going wrong:

In normal merge sort of numbers, the recurrence is: T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn ; where c is some constant

Notice what happens while solving this recurrence, and the difference while solving the recurrence T'(n) with c(n^2)

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + cn

T(n) = 2[2T(n/(2^2)) + c(n/2)] + cn

T(n) = (2^2)T(n/(2^2)) + cn + cn       **//after logn steps, 'cn' will be added logn times, therefore resulting in O(nlogn)**

---

T'(n) = 2T(n/2) + c(n^2)

T'(n) = 2[2T(n/(2^2)) + c((n/2)^2)] + c(n^2)

T'(n) = (2^2)T(n/(2^2)) + c(n^2)/2 + c(n^2)   **//every time n^2 is halving, which results in O(n^2)**

If you analyze the algorithm closely, (and as mentioned in arun's answer), the work done at each level is always n^2, and it doesn't halve at each level, and that's why the time complexity is O((n^2)logn) instead of simply O(n^2) by masters theorem.